# Confluent Platform: Source Connector (jdbc) keeps pulling old data

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent Platform 4.1.1 for transferring data from sql-server to Oracle database. 
For this, I am using timestamp+incrementing mode and confluent JDBC. 
But sometimes I see that source connector keep pulling same old data (that it has already synced before) again and again and keeps writing it to the Kafka log file because of which it is taking a lot of time to sync any new data that is inserted in the sql-server table.
In such a case, when I would check the consumer lag, it would be huge.

I thought this is happening since it is losing offset. I was using offset.retention of 24 hours (default). So I increased it to 7 days but still see the issue intermittently even though we have transactions every day.

Can somebody explain this behaviour. I would be happy to provide any further details if required.